# Change sender's address in mutt via console

Tags: mutt

I want to dynamically set the sender's address when using mutt via console (not composing). I checked everything which is described, tried everything from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158201/how-to-change-the-senders-name-or-e-mail-address-in-mutt) but nothing works. There is no change at all, no matter what I do.
I set

```
set from="sender@help.me"
set edit_headers=yes
```

in both the /etc/Muttrc and ~/.muttrc, also, I tried all sort of -e commands, like

```
-e "set from=email@example.com"
-e 'my_hdr From:sender@help.me'
-e "send-hook . 'my_hdr From: Other Name <otheremail\@example.com>'"
having export EMAIL=sender@help.me  in front
```

but I will always receive mails from username@compname.de

A typical call looks like this

```
export EMAIL="sender@help.me" && echo | mutt -s "VERSANDTEST" -c "mycc@help.me"  -e 'my_hdr From:sender@help.me' -a /opt/data/YoloDat.txt /opt/data/TroloDat.txt  -- "myaddress@help.me"  < /tmp/mailbody
```

Any more ideas appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use `set use_envelope_from = yes` in your .muttrc. This adds the -f option when calling sendmail to deliver the mail, forcing it to use the same address for the envelope as for the From: header field.

Setting `set edit_headers = yes` in .muttrc was not required to use the my_hdr-Flag on the command line.

```
echo "Test" | mutt -e "my_hdr From:sender@domain.tld" -- receiver@domain.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
export EMAIL="Name <from@address.com>";
echo "Test message body" | mutt -s "Test Subject" -- to@address.com;
```