# "From" address in mutt not working

Tags: shell, mutt

Refer this
[Change sender's address in mutt via console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446143/change-senders-address-in-mutt-via-console)

I have same issue in a shell script using mutt. Tried updating the header (-e), sending env variable EMAIL, updated ~/.muttrc (There is no entry in /etc/Muttrc so that does not have an effect) but no change.I still get "From" address as what is set by host.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some more options and this is what eventually worked.

$MUTT -e "set from=DoNotReply" -s "$MAIL_SUBJECT" -a $FILE_LIST -- $MAIL_RECEPIENTS

Answer (score 0):

Set `set use_envelope_from = yes` in your .muttrc. This adds the -f option when calling
sendmail to deliver the mail, forcing it to use the same address for the envelope as for the From: header field.