# sending a mail from terminal (Mac OS x) with custome domain name

Tags: bash, macos, email, mutt

I want to send a mail with custom sender domain name.

```
cat email_format.html | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html;" -s "Test mail - HTML" arun*****@gmail.com
```

If I use the above command from the terminal, mail has sent but the From address looks like this `From: arun.srinivasan@localdomain.localdomain`

I would like to have the sender mail id something like this `From: arun.srinivasan@mycompany.com`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158201/how-to-change-the-senders-name-or-e-mail-address-in-mutt ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've already tried that. It works perfectly when I use `mutt -e "set content_type=text/html;"`  without any from address. If I use from address like this `mutt -e "set content_type=text/html; my_hdr From:arun.srinivasan@mycompany.com"` command executed without error, but mail seems not received on the inbox or spam folder too.

Comment: isn't it multiple -e args `mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -e 'my_hdr From:sender@company.com'`. Does MAIL variable works?

Comment: No @KamilCuk. It's not working :(